# Digg/Stumbleupon Bar

Tags: digg

I'm looking to see if it's possible to implement a "bar" like you guys have, along with Digg, Stumble upon and other websites.

I have no idea what it's even called - frameset, iframe of sorts but I can't even think of a proper title to search google..

Can you help?

Comment: I think what they are called are annoyances.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a normal div tag (or whatever tag you want to use) with [CSS position](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp) property set to 'fixed'. Then the element can be positioned where ever you want and scrolling the page doesn't affect the position.